# single USB-C to drive 2 HDMI monitors in Extended desktop mode

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, usb-c

I have a new HP Spectre x360 laptop (15-bl152nr) with the latest 8th gen I7 processor and the following ports...

- 1 Thunderbolt™ 3 (Data Transfer up to 40 Gb/s, Power Delivery, DP1.2,
  HP Sleep and Charge);
- 1 USB 3.1 Type-C™ Gen 1 (Data Transfer up to 5
  Gb/s, Power Delivery, DP1.2, HP Sleep and Charge);
- 1 USB 3.1 Gen 1 (HP Sleep and Charge);

I am trying to find a USB-C docking station where I can run a single USB-C cable from the computer to the docking station and have the docking station drive two external HDMI displays.  And, on top of that, in Extended desktop mode with Windows 10.

Is this even possible?  I found a docking station on Amazon that seemed to be the answer, but I have it in hand, and it will only show all displays at the same time mirrored.  I need them in Extended mode.

[https://www.amazon.com/Wavlink-Universal-Docking-Station-Ethernet/dp/B06Y5B7BDD/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1511828954&sr=8-1&keywords=Wavlink+Universal+USB-C+Ultra+5K+Docking+Station+with+4K+Dual+Video+Outputs+and+Support+for+Mac%2CWindows+7%2F+8%2F+8.1%2F+10%28USB-C+in%2CDP+and+HDMI%2CGigabit+Ethernet%2CAudio+out+and+Mic+in%2C6+USB+3.0+Port%29](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06Y5B7BDD)

Comment: Wouldn't the HP offer a proper docking station to meet your needs for two HDMI displays? What do they say?

Comment: I've checked, and they don't.  All they have (as do most) is a docking station that drives one HDMI and one VGA.

Answer (score 0):

Reasonably inexpensive "mini docks" have recently come onto the market.

These offer either Dual HDMI or Dual Display Port plus a USB-A port. No power-passthrough.

CalDigit, MonoPrice, StarTech, and possibly other manufacturers seem to manufacture basically the same product.

- https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=31261
- [https://amazon.com/CalDigit-Thunderbolt-Portable-Charging-Ethernet/dp/B079H4WTR4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079H4WTR4)
- [https://amazon.com/dp/B07BJJX47G/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BJJX47G)

[image: Dual HDMI]